# How do I change the prompt of Windows commandline permanently?

Tags: windows, ms-dos, command-line-interface

I use Prompt command to temporarily change the Windows command prompt's inline prefix. So instead of current directory, I choose it to display something like current time and the $ sign.

But when I close the command window, my preference goes too.

How can I make my prompt preference permanent? I believe it requires some registry hacking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a "PROMPT" environment variable through the "Environment variables" dialog (My computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables).

You can specify it either as a User Specific variable, or as a System Variable. Both options should make it permanent.